# DJI sdk support mobile application

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to use dji-sdk for an ios app for iPhone without using any drone.

is that possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to buy a DJI aircraft in order to access the SDK, if that's what you're asking.

If you want to test your app with a DJI aircraft, you will need to buy one, since DJI's simulation setup requires the hardware in the loop.

Comment: is there a free version please?

Comment: @lafiraed https://developer.dji.com/login/?callback_url=https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

To start using DJI SDK:

1. Register an account at developer.dji.com. IT IS FREE.
2. Log in to your account, create an app. It will give you an app key based on the information you give. You will need to use the app key later
3. Follow this tutorial to integrate the SDK (enter your app key in one of the steps):
   http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#xcode-project-integration

DJI SDK has a lot of features, but to use any drone related feature, you need to get an actual DJI Product.